# Barra de rolagem na posição incorreta - DataGridView

Tags: winforms, vb.net, datagridview

Estou tentando selecionar a última linha em um DataGridView após incluir um novo item. Para isso estou executando o seguinte código:

```
dgwVenda.ClearSelection()
dgwVenda.Rows(dgwVenda.Rows.Count - 1).Selected = True
If dgwVenda.Controls(1).Visible = True Then
    dgwVenda.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgwVenda.Rows(dgwVenda.Rows.Count - 1).Index
End If
```

Após a execução a última linha está selecionada e aparecendo no Grid, porém a barra de rolagem (vertical) está na parte superior, quando deveria estar na parte inferior.
Além disso a rolagem do mouse (pelo scroll) não funciona.

Após a posição da barra ser alterada por um clique do mouse seu funcionamento volta a ficar correto.

Há alguma forma de a barra de rolagem ficar na posição inferior e a rolagem funcionar pelo scroll do mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objetivo for colocar o `Scroll` sempre posicionado na última linha, pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
dgwVenda.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgwVenda.RowCount - 1
```

Quanto ao `Scroll` da `DataGridView` não funcionar com o *scroll* do rato, pode dever-se ao facto da grelha perder o foco e, com isso, a possibilidade de utilizar o `Scroll`. Se assim for, pode "forçar" o foco ao passar com o rato na grelha:

```
Private Sub dgwVenda_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgwVenda.MouseEnter
    dgwVenda.Focus()
End Sub
```